# Left click only on Dijit MenuItem

Tags: javascript, dojo

using the basic tutorial here as example:
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/menus/demo/simpleProgMenu.html

I've noticed that there's no (obvious) way to differentiate between left and right clicks. I'd like right click to do nothing, but left click to call the onClick() on the menuitem.

Inspecting the contents of the event parameter passed to the onClick function, there doesn't appear to be anything telling me which mouse button was clicked.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want right click to do nothing, you don't have to do anything special. If you want to handle right clicks you can use the [dojo/mouse](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/mouse.html) module and its mouseButtons object.
An example from the documentation:

```
require(["dojo/mouse", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function(mouse, on, dom){
  on(dom.byId("someid"), "click", function(evt){
    if (mouse.isLeft(event)){
      // handle mouse left click
    }else if (mouse.isRight(event)){
      // handle mouse right click
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: When you say I don't have to do anything special, do you mean that standard behaviour has right click doing nothing? As that's not what I see from the above linked sample. Or that I don't have to do anything special after using dojo/mouse?

Comment: You are right about the demo, it seems that up to dojo 1.9 the default behaviour was to do nothing with the right click but with dojo 1.10 this has changed. You can use dojo/mouse to ignore the right clicks.